# What register in i386 stores the CPL?

Tags: x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, i386

I read in "INTEL 80386 PROGRAMMER'S REFERENCE MANUAL" (p112, S 6.3.1.3) that

> An internal processor register records the current privilege level
>   (CPL).

I am curious as to what register it refers to. Does it even have a name? What's the size of the register? Does it have any other use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Current Privilege Level (CPL) can always be found in the lower 2 bits of the Code Segment (*CS*) register. Those 2 bits can be the value 0b00 (ring 0), 0b01 (ring 1), 0b10 (ring 2), 0b11 (ring 3).

It should be noted that the old documentations use of *"An **internal processor register** records the current privilege level (CPL)"* is a bit deceptive and has caused some head scratching for others as well. *CS* always contains the CPL in the lower 2 bits but obviously it isn't an internal register.

The microarchitecture may have a copy of the CPL internally as well, but it is always accessible programmatically by looking at *CS*.

Not directly related to your question, but may be useful to know. If you transitioned between different rings and the destination code segment selector had a descriptor that is a [conforming segment](http://www.logix.cz/michal/doc/i386/chp06-03.htm), it's possible for the Descriptor Privilege Level (DPL) != CPL. This is because with a conforming segment you continue to run with the previous privilege level. With non-conforming segments DPL == CPL.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. But I am a little confused, since CS will be used to store a segment selector, which has the lower 2 bits as the RPL, how can the same location be used to store CPL?

Comment: @xtt: If I understand correctly:  If the "request" is allowed, it becomes the current.  Otherwise it faults and CS never takes the requested value.  i.e. RPL is the low 2 bits of something that you're trying to *make* current.

Comment: I think the reason it is distinguished is because the cpu causes some requests independent of the current context.  This permits interrupts and faults to be secured against the *int* instruction.  For example, issuing an *int $14* could confuse the kernel since the stack frame would be wrong, and might open an exploit.